# Email clients ignoring internal style sheet

Tags: css, html-email

Best practices in normal web development call for putting your styles between style tags or loading a style sheet; however, I've found out that several email clients will ignore any style tags and only execute inline styles (www.campaignmonitor.com). I can deal with that, but I'm not sure if CSS supports inline media queries. I would like my email to display a little different on the desktop. Is something similar to this supported?:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="@media screen and (max-width:480px;){ color:black; }"></div>
```

Comment: You can use `<style>` tags in the body, just not in the head (dont have a head)

Comment: No; that's totally impossible.  Sorry.

Comment: Here's a great resource of well documented [HTML email templates](http://mailchimp.com/resources/html-email-templates/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HTML emails are an entirely different beast.  You need to code them like it is 1999.  Use a very limited set of tags and make sure all or your styles are inline.  Use tables for your layouts.

To make use of media queries you need to do both.

What I recommend doing is to first create your email with all inline styles.  Then when you are happy with it you can add support for mobile.

To add support for mobile add the media queries to the head tag and use `!important` to override any inline styles.

Here is an example:
[Optimizing for mobile email](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3163/optimizing-your-emails-for-mobile-devices-with-media/)

Here is a helpful chart that details which css support for email clients.
http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: Thanks. I'm following a few of those tips like using tables, but my styles are not inline. I'm using Litmus and it looks like the majority of these browsers read the style sheet and apply the correct values based on the media query correctly, but if they have to be inline styles, and I out of luck with response email design?

Comment: You should be able to do both.  Make sure you have the inline styles for the major clients like gmail and outlook but add the media queries to the head with `!important` for the mobile support.

Comment: Perfect. I'm going to try this now.

Comment: Note though, that because media queries can't be inlined, they don't work in gmail.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think they work inline like that, you would probably have to embed the stylesheet in the HTML email template itself (e.g. `<style>@media {...}</style>`).

Even that seems like a VERY dodgy thing to rely on.  HTML emails are a huge pain in the ass because standards and CSS support are about a decade behind and there is massive variation among popular email clients in terms of which properties and types of styling are supported.

In general keeping it simple and using old school table based layouts with all inline CSS is the way to go.  Campaign Monitor has a [great chart of support for various CSS properties in major email clients and devices](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/).

Comment: Thanks! Campaign Monitor has been a huge help so far. The clients with decent CSS and HTML support look really great on desktop and mobile, but the big ones that aren't rendering correctly are Gmail and Outlook, so it's a broken product until then.

Comment: A note on Campaign Monitor though is that they have a tool that auto inlines their css before it is sent. When you read any suggestions etc, just remember this... If you want an inlining tool without using CM, try [premailer](http://premailer.dialect.ca/)

Answer (score 0):

A common workaround to the problem of HTML not rendering correctly in email clients is to do the best you can and have a prominent link at the top that says:  **"Email not displaying correctly? View it in your browser."**

Ray Kurzweil's weekly newsletter blast does this, and it's very well formed, and well done, and I always read it.  (It's a brilliant blend of content and presentation).

[image]

Comment: All emails should have a view in browser option. It is definitely best practice for html emails.